# Jquery AJAX for fetching JSON, affected by URL prefix (www vs. no www)?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, mime-types

I have come across a peculiar item in `JQuery` that I am hoping somebody can help me to understand.

I've spent much of the day trying to get `JQUERY's` `AJAX` '`success`' function to be raised when returning `JSON` from the server.

I checked the `JSON @ JSONLint` to ensure validity, checked encoding, tried different headers, but still PROBLEMS. 
After a couple hours, I switched the url (by accident!)

from

```
http//www.testing.com/_r4444/myfile.php
```

to the exact same thing `WITHOUT` the `www`... and it suddenly worked.

I have no clue why this would be the case - any ideas?

the snippet follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax( {
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       url: "http://testing.com/_r4444/getter.php", 
       beforeSend: function(x) {
         if(x && x.overrideMimeType) x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");           
       },
       data: "pass=TEST",
       dataType: "json",           
       error: function (xhr, status) { 
         alert(status); 
       }, 
       success: function (result) { 
         alert(result); 
       }    
    });             
});
```

Comment: BTW: Same result w/ JQuery 1.4, 1.5, 1.7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using "www" on the page in the browser?

Try switching the call to not include the domain, like:

"/_r4444/getter.php" instead of the full domain.

Comment: I posted this as I was leaving... As I was driving home, I thought of the same thing - and you are right! DOH...

My problem here and ultimately was that cross-domain AJAX requests w/ JSON aren't that straightforward... Easy enough fix though, just used JSONP (as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

ThX